# Regex to validate a number

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to resolve an issue with regex,within a text box i wish to have a number which is a 3 digit number,wherein the **1st digit** (i.e the number in hundreds position) should be **greater than or equal to 5**, and the following number in the **tens** place should be **greater than** the number in **hundreds place** (which is 5 in our case) and the number in **units place** should be **greater than** the number in **tens** place

e.g. valid strings  : 567,789,689,589
invalid string : 123,556,896,765

Comment: Often it is easier to extract certain information with a regular expression, but test conditions on the extracted information, instead of trying to validate via regex alone. So you could extract the digits and compare them in code.

Comment: that is my second thought but i was thinking of a possibility if it could be achieved using regex, would like to thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Even if it _could_ be achieved using regex, they are definitively the wrong tool for that.

Comment: If it could be done with a regex, I'd like to see it :)   Something along the ideas of /^([5-9])([\1-9])([\2-9])$/  but clearly that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:**
>
> Numerical comparison should generally be done through ordinary code not regex.
>   Both for efficiency and code readability reasons.

Here is the regex:
`[5-7][6-8](?<=5[6-8]|6[78]|78)[7-9](?<=6[7-9]|7[89]|89)`

A demo: https://regex101.com/r/nQfsE9/3

A breakdown:

```
\b                    # Ensures starting of a number
[5-7]                 # First digit can't be higher than 7
[6-8]                 # Second digit can't be higher than 8
(?<=5[6-8]|6[78]|78)  # Lookback checks second digit larger than third
[7-9]                 # Last digit must be at least 7
(?<=6[7-9]|7[89]|89)  # Lookback checks second digit larger than third
\b                    # Ensures ending of a number
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, as i am not so great with regex i had thought of an alternative will definitely consider your note before implementing the fix,wasn't aware of look back.. thank you for the quick response.